# Computing the limit using Taylor series $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{x^2\cdot \sin(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to use Taylor series to compute the following limit. I'm not the best with the following method so I'm trying my best to practice with it, and would be happy to receive feedback and support.

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{x^2\cdot \sin(x)}$

Given that :

$1-\cos^2(x) = \sin^2(x)$

The Taylor series expansion of $\sin^2(x)$ is:

$x^2 - \frac{x^4}{3} + \frac{(2 x^6)}{45} - \frac{x^8}{315} + O(x^9)$

And the Taylor series expansion for $x^2\sin(x)$ is:

$x^3 - \frac{x^5}{6} + \frac{x^7}{120} + O(x^9)$

Putting all of this together:

$$\frac{x^2 - \frac{x^4}{3} + \frac{(2 x^6)}{45} - \frac{x^8}{315} + O(x^9)}{x^3 - \frac{x^5}{6} + \frac{x^7}{120} + O(x^9)} \implies \frac{8}{21}?$$

I used wolfram to calculate the fraction as it was too large for me to compute. Though, have I approached this correctly, and was I right in picking the following fraction $\frac{8}{21}?$

Comment: $(1-\cos^2x)/(x^2\sin x)=(\sin x)/x^2$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the limit does not exist

Comment: The limit doesn't exist, since the expression is equivalent to $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ and $\sin x$ changes sign based on whether or not we are coming from the left or the right (and $\lim_{x\to 0}x^2$ isn't $\infty$).

Comment: @KentaS I was so focused on the taylor series, that I was blinded by the division of the square between the sine functions! This really simplifies the limit. Thanks

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^2}{x^3}$ does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, near $0$,\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{x^2\sin(x)}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-\frac13x^4+\cdots}{x^3-\frac16x^5+\cdots}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\frac13x^2+\cdots}{x-\frac16x^3+\cdots}\end{align}and this limit does not exist, since$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1-\frac13x^2+\cdots}{x-\frac16x^3+\cdots}=\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1-\frac13x^2+\cdots}{x-\frac16x^3+\cdots}=-\infty.$$

Comment: This makes things clearer! becuase $\frac{1}{x}$ diverges, right? Though, could you explain to me how you got the second limit $\frac{1-\frac{x^2}{3}}{x-\frac{x^3}{6}}$ from the previous?

Comment: I figured it out! you divided it by $x^2$. Elegant proof!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.